# Flask-SQLAlchemy application context error

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to use SQLAlchemy not in a view function (I was doing something like this with Flask-APSheduler).
I know that there were already a lot of topics related to this theme, but none of them were helpful to me.
So, first of all I will show my code:

***./run.py***

```
from app import create_app
from flask_config import DevConfig, ProdConfig

app = create_app(DevConfig)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
```

***./app/__init__.py***

```
from flask import Flask

from .node import node

from .models import db


def create_app(app_config=None):
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=False)
    app.config.from_object(app_config)
    db.init_app(app)

    app.register_blueprint(node)

    return app
```

***./app/models.py***

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

class Users(BaseFuncs, db.Model):
    ...
```

***./app/node.py***

```
from flask import Blueprint, request
from .bot import bot, secret
import telebot

node = Blueprint('node', __name__)


@node.route('/{}'.format(secret), methods=['POST'])
def handler():
    bot.process_new_updates([telebot.types.Update.de_json(request.get_data().decode('utf-8'))])
    return 'ok', 200
```

***./app/bot.py***

```
from flask import current_app as app

...

@bot.message_handler(commands=['test'])
def cmd_test(message):
    with app.app_context():
        print(Users.query.filter_by(id=0).first())
```

So when I am trying to call `cmd_test` from my application I am getting this error:

```
RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
to interface with the current application object in some way. To solve
this, set up an application context with app.app_context().  See the
documentation for more information.
```

I tried to use `g` variable and `before_request` methods, because every time before calling the database there is a call to the route 'handler', but this also doesn't work.
I also tried to use `db.get_app()`, but there was no effect.
So my question is how to call database right outside the views?

Comment: what is `@bot`? how you run `message_handler`? is it standalone process?

Comment: @Danila Ganchar it is a module `telebot` that allows to create bots for teleagram. I am using `Flask` as a webhook for my bot.

Comment: Happy New Year! ;) `telebot` don't know anything about `Flask` app. You can't use `current_app`. Try to use `from app import create_app; app = create_app(); with app.app_context(): ....`.

Comment: @ Danila Ganchar I also tried it, but got the same error

Comment: I tried to made something like local app with function `create_app()` in my `bot.py`

Comment: oh, finally it worked for me! thank you very much

Comment: I am pleased to ) good luck! ;)